# dropdown list atk4 quicksearch

Tags: atk4

i try to populate a dropdown menu for quicksearch in mvcgrid my code is:

```
 $g = $this->add('MVCGrid');
 $g->setModel('materiale');
 $g->addPaginator(25);
 $s = $g->addQuickSearch(array('nome_mat'));

 $value_list = array(
        1=>'Granito',
        2=>'Marmo'
    );

 $s->addField('dropdown','tipo_mat','Tipo_mat: ')->setValueList($value_list);
```

The dropdown list appear on quick search form.
My db field is tipo_mat, but when i click quicksearch button nothing uppens, can someone help me plase.
Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find that the [Quicksearch](https://github.com/atk4/atk4/blob/master/lib/QuickSearch.php) is nothing more that a simple form, which applies condition to your grid when submitted. In theory, you could have a standard form sitting in there doing the same thing:

```
$search = $g->add('Form',null,'quick_search',array('form/quicksearch','form'));
$search->addFiled('dropdown','tipo_mat')
    ->setValueList($value_list)
    ->set($_GET['tipo_mat']);
$search->addField('search','q')
    ->set($_GET['q']);

// Handle submit of form, reload grid with AjAX, pass values as arguments
if($search->isSubmitted()){
    $grid->js()->reload($search->getAllData())->execute();
}

// If values are passed, use them
if($_GET['q'])
    $grid->dq->where('name like','%'.$_GET['q'].'%');

if($_GET['tipo_mat'])
    $grid->dq->where('foo',$_GET['tipo_mat']);
```

The "Filter" and "QuickSearch" classes help you with saving search values but you must not be afraid to [look into their source](http://agiletoolkit.org/learn/understand/source) and create your own QuickSearch class which can apply parameters properly.

Perhaps using Filter in your case is better than quick search, because of how "applyDQ" is handled:

https://github.com/atk4/atk4/blob/master/lib/Filter.php#L62